# Change page in PageViewController from a page inside the controller?

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, uipageviewcontroller

I have a `UIPageViewController` that has 3 pages. How can I switch to a page that is within the `UIPageViewController` on a button tap? (Each of the pages are a separate `UIViewController` that I made in the storyboard).

I've tried a lot of code but I keep getting errors as I made my `UIPageViewController` inside my storyboard and I set it up like this:

`PageViewController.m`

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    self.dataSource = self;
    self.navigationController.navigationBarHidden = NO;

    [self setViewControllers:@[[self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"Main"]] 
                   direction:UIPageViewControllerNavigationDirectionForward 
                    animated:YES
                  completion:nil];
}

- (UIViewController *)pageViewController:(UIPageViewController *)pageViewController viewControllerBeforeViewController:(UIViewController *)viewController
{
    if ([viewController isKindOfClass:[NavView2ViewController class]])
       return nil;

    return [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"two"];
}

- (UIViewController *)pageViewController:(UIPageViewController *)pageViewController viewControllerAfterViewController:(UIViewController *)viewController
{
    if ([viewController isKindOfClass:[NavViewController class]])
        return nil;

    return [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"one"];
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do this a few different ways, depending on how you want to architect the rest of the app.

## [NSNotificationCenter](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSNotificationCenter_Class/)

Using notifications will allow you to decouple the child view controllers from the parent page view controller. It will be flexible enough to allow for additional code throughout the app to control which page is visible. However one disadvantage is that there is a level of indirection and it's not immediately apparent what has triggered the change of page.

Setup an observer on your `PageViewController`, something like:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    self.dataSource = self;
    self.navigationController.navigationBarHidden = NO;

    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self
                                             selector:@selector(handleButtonTap:)
                                                 name:MyPageViewControllerButtonNotification
                                               object:nil];

    [self setViewControllers:@[[self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"Main"]]
                   direction:UIPageViewControllerNavigationDirectionForward
                    animated:YES
                  completion:nil];
}

- (void)handleButtonTap:(NSNotification *)notification
{
    // Determine which page to move to based
    // on the notification object or userInfo
}
```

And post the notification from any of the child view controllers:

```
- (void)buttonTapped:(id)sender
{
    // Customise the sender or userInfo in order to
    // pass further information with the notification.
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] postNotificationName:MyPageViewControllerButtonNotification
                                                        object:sender
                                                      userInfo:nil];
}
```

You will need to create the string `MyPageViewControllerButtonNotification` in a file common to both your `PageViewController` and all view controllers you wish to post this notification from.

## [Delegates](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/General/Conceptual/CocoaEncyclopedia/DelegatesandDataSources/DelegatesandDataSources.html)

Using a delegate pattern will provide tighter coupling between view controllers and the page view controller than notifications, which may make it more difficult to extend later. The advantage of this is it's easy to track where a page change originated.

Define a protocol in a file common to your page view controller and child view controllers:

```
@protocol PageControlDelegate <NSObject>

- (void)moveToPage:(NSUInteger)pageNumber;

@end
```

Ensure your page view controller conforms to that protocol:

```
@interface PageViewController : UIPageViewController <PageControlDelegate>
```

(And implement the method in `PageViewController.m`)

```
- (void)moveToPage:(NSUInteger)pageNumber
{
    // switch to the appropriate page
}
```

When you are creating the view controllers for the pages that need the button interaction you will need to supply a (**weak**) reference to your `PageViewController`:

```
@interface SomeChildViewController : UIViewController

@property (nonatomic, weak) id<PageControlDelegate> pageControlDelegate;

@end
```

And an example assignment when setting up the next page:

```
- (UIViewController *)pageViewController:(UIPageViewController *)pageViewController viewControllerAfterViewController:(UIViewController *)viewController
{
    if ([viewController isKindOfClass:[NavViewController class]])
        return nil;

    SomeChildViewController *childController = [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"one"];

    childController.pageControlDelegate = self;

    return childController;
}
```

Then you can directly invoke this method from any child view controllers that have a `pageControlDelegate`:

```
- (void)buttonTapped:(id)sender
{
    NSUInteger pageNumber = // Decide which page to move to
    [self.pageControlDelegate moveToPage:pageNumber];
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much!!!! I added your code and it works however it removes the "Main" View controller each time and I am left with the view controller that I move to and the one I was just on. I am using the notification method. Inside the "handleButtonTap" method in my PageViewController I have added the [self setViewControllers] method and I can't instantiate the Main one without it crashing, and instead I just instantiate the view I am moving too. This is the best solution I have seen so far, but do you know what I could do to make the Main view controller not go away?

Comment: The page view controller's viewControllerBefore/AfterViewController methods will need to be modified to return the correct view controller that is now before/after the one currently being displayed. If you start with Main and the before controller is "two" and after controller is "one", when switching to "two" your before controller would become nil and after controller would become "main". It took me a little while to figure out how `UIPageViewController` works, but it's essentially always displaying 1 view controller, with 1 before and 1 after. Hope that helps.

Comment: One way I have used `UIPageViewController` in the past is to keep an array of `UIViewController`s in memory along with the currently displayed index, then the before/after delegate methods can use that index and return the view controller that is plus or minus 1 in the array (and nil when at the bounds). Though this approach may be memory intensive.

Comment: Oh ok, everything now works! Thank you again, this helped me a ton

Comment: No problem, glad to help

Answer (score 0):

You can call `setViewController` as often as you want. Call it again, with the `ViewController` you want. You could also try to find you `ViewController` by accessing the `viewControllers` property. But I think, that this attribute will only show you the current `ViewController` which is being displayed.

Answer (score 0):

This is what I came up with and it requires no dark magic and delegates. Let's say you have your custom `PageViewController` class called `MyPageViewController` and you instantiate and keep your child view controllers in `viewControllerList`:

**Swift 4**

```
class MyPageViewController: UIPageViewController, UIPageViewControllerDataSource {

  lazy var viewControllersList: [UIViewController] = {
    let storyBoard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
    let first = storyBoard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "FirstViewController")
    let second = storyBoard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "SecondViewController")

    return [first,
            second]
  }()
}
```

Now inside your child view controllers, you can switch to the next view controller in the following way. In this example I perform the switch as a table row is selected:

**Swift 4**

```
  override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    if let pageViewController = self.parent as? MyPageViewController {
      if let currentIndex = pageViewController.viewControllersList.index(of: self) {
        guard (pageViewController.viewControllersList.count - currentIndex) > 1 else {
          fatalError("Can't navigate to the next view controller!")
        }
        let nextViewController = pageViewController.viewControllersList[currentIndex + 1]
        pageViewController.setViewControllers([nextViewController], direction: .forward, animated: true, completion: nil)
      }
    }
  }
```